# Clear actionbar in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have couple of fragments with NavigationDrawer. One of the fragment's actionbar has Spinner and others have just the title.

Now when I open the fragment which has spinner in actionbar and then click on the navigation drawer to open the another fragment class. The actionbar has the spinner and then title.

How do I clear the actionbar just to show the title and not the spinner? I mean clear the actionbar and show what is required.

Let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to Second fragment(which has only title to display), in it's `onStart()` method, you can disable/hide the Spinner, using below code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

You then need to add code in your first fragment to show Spinner again!

Answer (score 0):

I think invoking invalidateOptionsMenu() should work. You should invoke this method when opening your second fragment.

Comment: Tried calling getActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); didn't work. Do I need to add anything else?